# linq-To-Sql: filter with enum(flags)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum EmailType
{
    PasswordRecovery = 1,
    Activation = 2,
    SendTicket = 4
}
```

For example, in a table we have value equals 3 that means - `PasswordRecovery`, `Activation`.
This is my query:

```
var emailType = EmailType.PasswordRecovery;
return Database.EmailSettings.FirstOrDefault(es => es.EmailType ==  (int)emailType);
```

Of course this query not works properly:`3 == 1 => false`.
How to filter properly?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I'm using `Flags` attribute because there is one more application written with XAF (devexpress framework) and I have one feature in UI that required `Flags` attribute.

Comment: EmailType.RecoveryPassword  or EmailType.PasswordRecovery?

Comment: > es => es.EmailType ==  (int)emailType... for FLAGS? That is not how flags should work, unless you look for a 100% match. Why is that a flags enum to start with? Bit fields, isntead of coded value? RecoveryPassword+SendTicket in ONE sending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int emailType = (int)EmailType.PasswordRecovery;
return Database.EmailSettings.FirstOrDefault(es => (es.EmailType & emailType) == emailType);
```

**Edit:** I added a cast since `es.EmailType` is and `int`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Database.EmailSettings.FirstOrDefault(
    es => es.EmailType.HasFlag(EmailType.PasswordRecovery));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `EmailType == 3` is one of your conditions? Maybe you can get the results using other conditions first, and then filter with this condition in C# code using [Enum.HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method. If this is the only condition you want to query, maybe you can store "1,2" instead of "3" in DB.

Comment: I can't store as `1,2` because I have one more application (wrote with `XAF` (Devexpress framework)) and XAF required enum with `Flags` attribute.